# How to check if a foreign column is part of a constraint with "ON DELETE CASCADE" option?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm performing a query to avoid constraint violation when removing rows from the database. Whenever possible I am using `ON DELETE CASCADE` options, but there are times that I don't want to allow the delete to be executed.

For an example:

CASE:

1. I have a DEPT table with a column ID
2. I have a CUSTOMER table with a column DEPTID referencing the DEPT table 
     without any ON DELETE CASCADE options.
3. I have a AREA table with a column DEPTID referencing the DEPT table with 
     the ON DELETE CASCADE option.

The query below will list the two tables (CUSTOMER and AREA) referencing the DEPT table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
JOIN sys.columns col ON
     fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id 
     AND fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id
WHERE object_name(referenced_object_id) = 'DEPT'
```

However I want to display in my query only the tables that have foreign keys **without** the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, in the example above just the table CUSTOMER.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select ao.name,ao.type_desc,delete_referential_action_desc,*
from sys.foreign_keys fk 
inner join sys.all_objects ao 
on fk.parent_object_id = ao.object_id     
where delete_referential_action_desc <> 'CASCADE'
```

Comment: I tend to go for INFORMATION_SCHEMA views instead of directly referencing sys tables, but it would come out the same in the end.

Comment: Strangely this does not tell you what tables or columns the constraint depends on / references. Need to simply right-click the table name in SQL Management Server -> Script table as -> Create to -> New window, then you can see the full constraint info

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
JOIN sys.columns col ON
     fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id 
     AND fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id
WHERE object_name(referenced_object_id) = 'DEPT'
AND  objectproperty(fkc.constraint_object_id , 'CnstIsDeleteCascade')=1
```